# ajax doesn't work with javascript / salvattore

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button calling an ajax function which loads a PHP script returned as innerHTML. It does return the output to the screen but the problem looks to be that it is not implementing javascript to format the outputted HTML. So I should have 6 boxes per line (dictated by salvattore.js) but instead it stretches 1 div across the screen. I can also tell my own js is not initialised until I do a window resize. Heres the script..

```
function submitForms() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {     

  document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ideasSearch.php?",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

Comment: Is your responseText already be formed to html markups? For exampe: https://jsfiddle.net/dL294ett/1/

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Essentially I took a PHP script that was on my main page working perfectly and put it into a seperate PHP file which is now called by clicking a button and using ajax. It loads all CSS formatting fine. Just not JS.

Comment: So HTML and CSS formatting all fine. Just not JS. I've also tried including the .js files in my called .php file but still doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly a cross-domain issue. Are you loading the HTML page from the file system, or is it the same server as the PHP? You should do some testing, example: `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` - just to see what you're getting back.

Comment: So both php files are in the main webpage directory which I am running under localhost. I'm not sure what to look for in the console log? I can go to network tab in console to see the GET request to my .php file which shows the HTML returned is the same as it would look if on the page it's returned to. Anything I should be looking for?